# Ошибка с passport js vkontakte(nest js)

Tags: javascript, nestjs, passport

Всем привет. Я пытаюсь настроить выполнение входа через vk, для этого использую @nestjs/passport passport-vkontakte. Собственно, почти такой же функционал я уже реализовал для входа ччерез google и там все работает хорошо. Но при входе через вк, почему-то, возникает ошибка `VKontakteStrategy: verify callback must take 4 or 5 parameters`. Все те параметры, которые должна принимать функция она принимает. Но, кажется, VKStrategy вызывает, почему-то, не тот метод. Я открыл исходный код, где как раз и высчитавается количество аргументов, которое принимает метод, поставил там `console.log(verify.length)`, которые выводит значение 0.
Вот код моей стратегии:

```
import {Injectable} from "@nestjs/common";
import {PassportStrategy} from "@nestjs/passport";
import {Strategy, Profile, VerifyCallback} from "passport-vkontakte";

import {HelperService} from "../../helper/helper.service";


@Injectable()
export class VKStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, "vkontakte") {
    constructor(private helperService: HelperService) {
        super({
            clientID: process.env.VK_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.VK_SECRET,
            callbackURL: process.env.VK_REDIRECT_URI,
            scope: ['profile'],
        });
    }

    async validate(accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: Profile, done: VerifyCallback): Promise<any> {
        console.log('verify')
        const payload = this.helperService.createAuthPayload(profile);

        done(null, payload);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я не так давно тоже столкнулся с этой проблемой - насколько я понял в пакете `passport-vkontakte` реализация немного отличается от остальных (могу судить по Google и Yandex, подключение которых было идентичным). В данном случае метод `validate(...)` не вызовется, вместо него нужно передать обработчик в конструкторе вторым аргументом после `options` примерно так:

```
constructor(private helperService: HelperService) {
    super({
        clientID: process.env.VK_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.VK_SECRET,
        callbackURL: process.env.VK_REDIRECT_URI,
        scope: ['profile'],
    }, function (
       accessToken: string,
       refreshToken: string,
       params: Params,
       profile: Profile,
       done: VerifyCallback
    ) {

      // ...какая-то логика

      return done(null, {
         profile: {
           name: profile.displayName,
           // ...любые другие данные
         }
      });
    });
}
```

После этого данные будут доступны в в колбеке после редиректа в `req.user.profile`